# Records duplicating in database during checkout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to learn/make mvc 5 e commerce web application. Every thing works fine except when purchasing an item. The item duplicates in the database instead of subtracting the quantity of the purchased product. How should i change my code to do that?

I have tried multiple ways of connecting product id with order item product id but i get errors instead. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
public ActionResult Checkout(string firstName, string lastName, string address, string email, string phone)
        {
            Order order = new Order();

            order.firstName = firstName;
            order.lastName = lastName;
            order.user = User.Identity.Name;
            order.phone = phone;
            order.email = email;
            order.address = address;

            List<OrderItem> orderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
            foreach (CartItem item in (List<CartItem>)Session["cart"]){
                OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem();

                orderItem.Order = order;
                orderItem.Product = item.Product;
                orderItem.quantity = item.Quantity;
                orderItems.Add(orderItem);
            }

            order.orderItems = orderItems;



            _context.Orders.Add(order);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            Session["cart"] = null ;

            return RedirectToAction("PaymentSuccess", "Checkout");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are adding the items from your cart by calling

> orderItems.Add(orderItem)

Your context will treat this as a new item. You have two options here:

- tell the context that this is an existing entity by calling `_context.Items.Attach(orderItem)`
- reload the item from the context, e.g. by calling `orderItems.Add(_context.Items.Single(x => x.id == orderItem.Id)`

Check [Working with entity states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state) for the details.

Comment: The duplication is gone but order records are not being saved anymore.

Comment: Not sure how your code looks now, make sure to attach the item before linking it to the order: first attach the item, then link the order and item, then add order. If you attach it with the already linked order it will treat both as existing